# Can't run java through vim

Tags: java, vim, cmd

I'm trying to learn java, and since I'm using 'javac' and 'java' all day, I'm using vim as my editor of choice. But I'm having a problem getting this system to work: I can't even get a minimal "Hello World" program to run! Within vim, I can use `:!javac %` to compile the current file just fine. However, with a file Test.java, any attempt to call `:!java Test` yields an UnsupportedClasVersionError, even though the same command works fine outside of vim. I'm completely stumped.

I'm using java7 on windows 7 (64bit) with cmd.exe as my shell.

Comment: Within vim, try and execute `javac -version` and `java -version` --> is it the same? Do you have several JDKs installed?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! But I'm curious why one would work on the command line, but not in vim. I thought the commands would be interpreted the exact same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java you invoke is an older version than the Javac you invoke.

You most likely have a Java 6 JRE installed (for browser plugins etc) at system level and a Java 7 JDK installed which you've added at the end of your path.

Either tell Javac to produce Java 6 compatible class files (with `-target`) or put the JDK in the front of  your path.